# Sed editing of large text file much faster than native bash substring replacement?

Tags: bash, sed, bash-scripting

I have a ~19MB text file which I would like to perform many find/replace operations on. I originally wrote the script to loop over inplace sed operations e.g.

```
sed -i "s|$pattern|$replacement|g" $textfile
```

Each of these takes ~0.5 seconds in my case. I thought I might be able to speed things up by loading the text into memory and then looping over native bash substring replacement instead, e.g.

```
 text=$(<$textfile)
 text=${text//$pattern/$replacement}
```

But to my surprise, each replacement take about 7.5 seconds (15x longer), not including the initial load or subsequent save. Why is sed so much faster than native bash string replacement? I ended up using

```
text=$(sed "s|$pattern|$replacement|g" <<< "$text")
```

which is ~20% faster than just doing inplace seds each time, but again was surprised that ${text//$pattern/$replacement} was so slow. It's not even close. Is there a more efficient syntax? I'm using GNU bash 5.1.16(1).

Comment: If you have multiple replacements, you can generally do them all in a single pass of `sed` with multiple `-e` options: `sed -i -e "s|$pat1|$repl1|g" -e "s|$pat2|$repl2|g" -e "s|$pat3|$repl3|g" ...` (or, if you prefer, `sed -i "s|$pat1|$repl1|g; s|$pat2|$repl2|g; s|$pat3|$repl3|g; ..."`).

Comment: Hypothesis, a hunch, therefore not an answer. `sed` works line by line, writing each processed line to the output file. Not-yet-read lines are not a burden. Your bash holds all the data in `$text` and probably *each* single replacement requires rewriting (shifting) *everything that follows* (unless `$pattern` and `$replacement` are of the same length in bytes, but I think Bash is not optimized for this anyway). This happens in memory, but `sed` also works mainly in memory due to caching. In general Bash (or any shell) by itself is not a good tool for processing data.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at sed's `-f` option.